# How can I test a modal inside of a React Portal using React Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-portal

I'm trying to test my `Modal` component with React Testing Library. The Modal is rendered inside of a React Portal. Now when I try to match my `Modal` with a snapshot the snapshot gets rendered as an empty div.

```
test('The component should render in body when open', () => {
    const {container} = render(
        <Modal>
            <div>My dialog content</div>
        </Modal>
    );

    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

The snapshot I get looks like this:

```
exports[`The component should render in body when open 1`] = `<div />`;
```

I've seen a few workarounds for instance passing `{container: document.body}` as a second argument to the `render()` function. But nothing really worked.

Also I cannot query for any elements via `container`. It always returns `null`.

```
const dialog = container.querySelector(".modal");
console.log(dialog); // null
```

Comment: Can you show the code of the `Modal`?

Comment: I doubt I can share it here, unfortunately. It's a pretty bold component. But essentially everything returns in one big `<Portal></Portal>` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually made it work by snapshotting `baseElement` instead of `container` Both are returned properties by the `render()` function.

```
test('The component should render in body when open', () => {
    const {baseElement} = render(
        <Modal>
            <div>My dialog content</div>
        </Modal>
    );

    expect(baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should identify the container element of your portal, that "root" node that is added within the body to hold the portal content. Then you should manually append/add it in the DOM so that your render method knows where to render your Modal component. Then you should use the baseElement property instead of the container, since the portal element is rendered within the body and then test the firstChild of your baseElement (which is the actual portal element) against the snapshot.

This worked for me:

```
it('should render', () => {
  document.body.innerHTML = '<div id="my-root-element-id" />';
    
  const { baseElement } = render(<Default />);
    
  expect(baseElement.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```